# php class pass in undefined variables

Tags: php

I am trying to make a class that can process strings with un defined variables. Is this possible? or is there a better way?
For instance, if I have the following and would like this class Looper to take `$str_1` and output it with the variables `$fname` and `$lname` filled out ... then somewhere else i can reuse Looper class and process `$str_2` since they both need `$fname` and `$lname`.

```
class Looper {
    public function processLoop($str){
        $s='';
        $i=0;
        while ($i < 4){
            $fname = 'f' . $i;
            $lname = 'l' . $i;

            $s .= $str . '<br />';
            $i++;
        }
        return $s;
    }
}

$str_1 = "First Name: $fname, Last Name: $lname";
$rl = new Looper;
print $rl->processLoop($str_1);

$str_2 = "Lorem Ipsum $fname $lname is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";
print $rl->processLoop($str_2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$str_1 = "First Name: %fname%, Last Name: %lname%";
echo strtr($str_1, array('%fname%' => $fname, '%lname%' => $lname));
```

So in the context if your class:

```
public function processLoop($str){
    $s='';
    $i=0;
    while ($i < 4){
        $tokens = array('%fname%' => 'f' . $i, '%lname%' => 'l' . $i);
        $s .= strtr($str, $tokens) . '<br />';
        $i++;
    }
    return $s;
}
```

Likewise if you dont want to be dependent on named placeholders you could use positional placeholders via [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
public function processLoop($str){
    $s='';
    $i=0;
    while ($i < 4){
        $s .= sprintf($str, 'f' . $i, l' . $i) . '<br />';
        $i++;
    }
    return $s;
}
```

In that case your `$str` argument would look like `"First Name: %s, Last Name: %s"`

So over all usage:

```
// with strtr

$str_1 = "First Name: %fname%, Last Name: %lname%";
$rl = new Looper;
print $rl->processLoop($str_1);


// with sprintf

$str_1 = "First Name: %s, Last Name: %s";
$rl = new Looper;
print $rl->processLoop($str_1);
```